# Iterating over 12 items specify markup up on nth items

Tags: php, iterator, iteration

Hi I am using Bootstrap 2 with a PHP content management system.

I am rendering 12 items from the database, each 3 items needs to be wrapped in a row. However I am unable to achieve this my last attempt is below (with simplified markup):

```
$i = 1;
                echo "<div class='row-fluid'>";
                foreach($posts as $p) {
                    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
                        echo "<div class='row-fluid'>";
                    }
                    echo "<div class='span4'><h5>$p->title</h5></div>";

                    $i++;  

                }
```

In affect what I am looking for is something like this:

```
    <div class="row">
           <div class="item></item>
           <div class="item"</item>
           <div class="item"></item>
        </div>
<div class="row">
           <div class="item></item>
           <div class="item"</item>
           <div class="item"></item>
        </div>
<div class="row">
           <div class="item></item>
           <div class="item"</item>
           <div class="item"></item>
        </div>
<div class="row">
           <div class="item></item>
           <div class="item"</item>
           <div class="item"></item>
        </div>
```

I have tried everything I can think of any help would be great thanks.

Comment: what is the output of your PHP code ? I think you need nested loops to do this better.

Comment: what does var_dump($posts) look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if there are 12 rows :

```
         echo "<div class='row-fluid'>";
            foreach($posts as $p) {
                echo "<div class='span4'><h5>$p->title</h5></div>";
                if ($i % 3 == 0) {
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo ( $i< 12 )? "<div class='row-fluid'>" : "";  
                }
                $i++;  
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
                $i = 0;
                echo "<div class='row-fluid'>";
                foreach($posts as $p) {

                    echo "<div class='span4'><h5>$p->title</h5></div>";
                    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
                        echo "</div><div class='row-fluid'>";
                    }

                    $i++;  

               }
               echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Thank you that helped, I have one extra row but thats easy to remove.